# Is it possible to preload an entire HTML5 video source before playing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, preload

***Solution***

I created a working example of the accepted answer which uses an XHR and reports loading progress through a bar.

It's available here.

https://github.com/synthecypher/full-preload

***Question***

I've noticed when I create a `<video>` element with sources and call `load()` it will load to about 36% and then stops unless you `play()` it, at which time it'll continue to load the rest of the video as it plays.

However, I want to ensure the entire video loaded before hand as it's an element in a timed exercise and if the internet connection drops during the exercise I will have to detect such an event and restart the exercise.

I assume this is a built in feature of the HTML5 media elements but is it possible to override this native functionality?

I've attempted to load the entire video source as a `arraybuffer` using an `XMLHttpRequest` which is then converted to a blob and set as the `src` of a `<source>` element in my `<video>` element.

This does work however, it isn't ideal as I can't report the progress of download to the user through the use of progress bar as an XHR is a syncronous operation and will cause my JavaScript to hang until a response is received. I know XHR2 now has this funtionality but I have to support IE8+ so that's not an option.

Is there an easier more elegant solution to my problem, which will report progress?

**Requirements**

- Need to preload the entire `<video>` element's `<source>` before playing.
- Need to report progress of the

Comment: Have you tried the [`preload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attr-preload) attribute?

Comment: You do know that the video tag is not supported by IE8, right?

Comment: @jlowcs: I'm wrapping it in videos which creates a Flash fallback if required.

Comment: @Oriol: Yes but ```preload="auto"``` will only preload it partially and in some cases on iOS not at all.

Comment: @jlowcs does anybody actually still care about ie8? Must users that actually care about what you're doing will be using a modern browser. I also think the same way for app, I'm not making my apps hard to maintain because there are some still using android 2.3. Too bad, upgrade your device. :)

Comment: @PanamaJack sadly some big companies still have systems on location that only have IE8 and are slow moving when it comes to rolling out up to date software and hardware.

Comment: @SyntheCypher you are correct about that my company being one of them.:) But most of us use Chrome or FF here. Also you are doing a flash fallback so you are covering the crap browser anyway. :)

Comment: @PanamaJack well in matter of fact they should be getting FF in the coming months but this product has to deliver before then. Yes videojs is handling Flash fallback.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have the source, you can pre-download the data to a blob in JavaScript and play when ready.

The following should work if the video is on your server. If not, you'll run into CORS issues.

```
var video = document.getElementById("Your video element id")

var url = "Some video url"

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", url, true);
xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";

xhr.onload = function(oEvent) {

    var blob = new Blob([oEvent.target.response], {type: "video/yourvideosmimmetype"});

    video.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    //video.play()  if you want it to play on load
};

xhr.onprogress = function(oEvent) {

    if (oEvent.lengthComputable) {
        var percentComplete = oEvent.loaded/oEvent.total;
        // do something with this
    }
}

xhr.send();
```

Comment: This works thank you, I've also included a working example in my original post.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28852298/why-cant-my-android-device-play-html5-video-loaded-as-blob-via-xhr

Comment: Unfortunately chromium crashes when the blob is over 2MB (so I read somewhere). And thats the case pretty much for all videos

Comment: I just checked this on Chromium 63.0.3239.132, on a Ubuntu 17.10 64-bit, works just fine on a 4.4 MB video, and with a 25 MB video

Comment: Is it possible to preload the beginning part of the video ?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a sample to preload full video using XHR . but you need to handle CORS by yourself.

```
var xhrReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhrReq.open('GET', 'yourVideoSrc', true);
xhrReq.responseType = 'blob';

xhrReq.onload = function() {
    if (this.status === 200) {
        var vid = URL.createObjectURL(this.response);
        video.src = vid;
    }
}
xhrReq.onerror = function() {
    console.log('err' ,arguments);
}
xhrReq.onprogress = function(e){
    if(e.lengthComputable) {
        var percentComplete = ((e.loaded/e.total)*100|0) + '%';
        console.log('progress: ', percentComplete);
    }
}
xhrReq.send();
```