# How to "pre-load" entire video file from URL while playing in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, video

I have a video download link but it expires before the video is finished playing. How can I **"preload"** the rest of the video while it's playing? Video size can be over **2GB** in **.mp4** format.

I tried the following but it didn't work:

```js
const videoURL = "MY_VIDEO_URL";
const video = document.getElementById("video");
// Repeat this with next range
fetch(videoUrl, { headers: { range: "bytes=0-1567139" } })
  .then(response => response.blob())
  .then(blob => {
    video.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
   });
```

Comment: May duplicate of / similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28839449/is-it-possible-to-preload-an-entire-html5-video-source-before-playing ?